# Returning Objects with JavaScript Reduce

Tags: javascript, methods, reduce

On FreeCodeCamp, I was introduced to this snippet of code:

```
const users = [
  { name: 'John', age: 34 },
  { name: 'Amy', age: 20 },
  { name: 'camperCat', age: 10 }
];

const usersObj = users.reduce((obj, user) => {
  obj[user.name] = user.age;
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(usersObj);

// expected result : { John: 34, Amy: 20, camperCat: 10 }
```

I've been looking at this for a while now and just can't wrap my head around how the reduce function works here. In my view it works as follows in the first iteration:

```
**ITERATION 1:**
Initial Accumulator (obj): {}
CurrVal (user): {name: 'John', age: 34}
Updated Accumulator: {}[{name: 'John', age: 34}.name] = {name: 'John', age: 34}.age;
```

But immediately there, it goes wrong in my console when trying this step by step, as I understand the Updated Accumulator is basically saying `["John"] = 34` Why are we setting the name equal to the age?

What am I missing here to connect the missing pieces? Why does the above code work?

Comment: `obj[user.name]` seems to create a property on `obj` with the name `user.name` and then assigns it the value `user.age`.

Comment: If you expect the result to be `{ John: 34, ... }`, then surely you must set the key to the name and its value to the age…?!

Comment: Try `const u = {}; u['John'] = 34; console.log(u);`…?

Comment: @deceze, you seem to be able to point out some of my confusion: `const u = {}; u['John'] = 34; console.log(u);` works perfectly fine while doing this in one go `{}['John'] = 34` throws an error.

Comment: That's just a bad test because the meaning of `{}` is ambiguous here. `({}['John']) = 34` would do, but the result will be discarded immediately because the object you're creating on the fly here isn't assigned to anything, so you won't see the resulting object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, the flow you're describing *is* what's happening, but it's not valid JS, the way it was written.

If I tweak the code a bit into valid JS, this is what you get:

```js
//**ITERATION 1:**
let accumulator = {};
console.log('Accumulator:\n', accumulator);

let currVal = {name: 'John', age: 34};
console.log('Current value:\n', currVal);

accumulator[currVal.name] = currVal.age;
console.log('Updated accumulator:\n', accumulator)
```